# How to profile on iOS?

Tags: ios, profiling

I'm using instruments to profile the CPU activity of an iOS game.

The problem I'm having is that I'm not entirely sure what the data I'm looking at represents.

Here is the screen I see after running my game for a couple of minutes,

[image]

I can expand the call tree to see exactly what methods are using the most CPU time. I'm unsure if this data represents CPU usage for the entire duration the profiler was running or is it just at that point in time.

I've tried running the slider along the timeline to see what effect that has on the numbers and it doesn't seem to have any. So that leeds me to believe the data represents CPU usage for the duration the game was running.

If this is the case then is it possible to access CPU usage at a particular point in time. There are a few spikes along the time line, I would like to see exactly what was happening at that time to see if there are any improvements I can make.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: Also, it's sometimes useful to check "Invert Call Tree" and "Hide System Libraries", so you can identify which of your methods are accounting for the most time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select a time range, use the "inspection range" buttons at the top of the window (left of the stop watch).

First select the start of the range by clicking on the graph ruler, the press the left most button to select the left edge. Then select the end of the range on the graph ruler and press the right most button to select the right edge.

Comment: I have no idea how I didn't spot those buttons >_< Thank you.